# Unique ID of Android app

Tags: android

What is the unique id of android application? Is it package name? Can there be two applications with the same packages names on one device?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 2 different things: the Java package and the Android Application package. The second one needs to be Unique.

There is a good article about it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160302043541/http://blog.javia.org/android-package-name/)

Comment: @SeanCheey thanks for catching the issue with the link!  I approved your edit since it was a useful contribution, but for future reference, you can often find the old contents of such links via https://web.archive.org/, which I've used to restore the link to its previous, non-spammy state.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the package name is the unique identifier for an android application in the market.

No, there can't be two apps with the same package name in the market/on the device.

Comment: Thanks for answer. And what will happen if I'll install app from apk-file with package name which already in use by another app on the device?

Comment: The installation of the new app will fail. The market will deny an upload of an app with an already existing package name. so the only case that this can happen is when you download from custom locations.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add one little clarification that wasn't mentioned here.

Although there can't be two apps with the same package name, there can be several launcher activities within one app that user can see in launcher app. For example, standard "Maps" application ("com.google.android.apps.maps" package) has several launcher activities like "Local", "Navigation", "Maps". It doesn't matter for user if these "apps" (or activities, in developer terms) are implemented in one application package or not.

Activity name ("com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity") is not unique itself too, because anyone can create an app with unique package name and an activity located in java package com.google.android.maps called MapsActivity.

Thus, if you want to find unique identifier for all these launcher activities, you should use combination of both app package name ("com.google.android.apps.maps") and activity name ("com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity").

Answer (score 2):

The unique identifier for Android apps is now the `applicationId` field in the `build.gradle` file. Devices will determine whether an app is an update to an existing app or a new app based on that field.

Comment: I already have uploaded crossword app of 9x9 cells with `applicationid:com.drulapp.padashri` and `package-name:com.drulapp.padashri` (ie in all sourcecode and in `AndroidManifest.xml` ).  
Can I have applicationid like `com.drulapp.padashri.seven` for 7x7 cells crossword with package name **unchanged** (of-course by copying entire app folder and changing appid and signing details?

Comment: my concern is also about how internal storage are provided if package names are same and applicationid is different.

Answer (score 1):

Package name must be different, you can't upload an app with same package name like an existing one.