# How to differentiate the applications with same name in android?

Tags: android

In android I am listing the installed application list and storing in my private db. In that some application have same name, example there are 4 application named Maps, If one  application gets update, other 3 applications records in private db get updated. How to differentiate those applications? I have used following code to get the installed application list.

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    ArrayList<String> applist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> packlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
        packlist.add(rInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
        applist.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm)
                .toString());
    }
```

Comment: They should be updated by package name.

Comment: get the UID of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use install paths as unique identifiers (they won't be installed in the same dir).

On the other hand, read [this](http://blog.javia.org/android-package-name/) article if you have time. Packages have their configuration which contains UID. The link is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951917/unique-id-of-android-app) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't differentiate two applications by their names. Some applications don't even have names associated with them (i.e. they are empty). The only sure way to distinguish two applications is by their package name (and this is heavily used by OS too).

Also note that while package name will always be the same, the UID of the application might change if application is fully uninstalled and then reinstalled again.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked it, Those applications package name and uid's also same.

Comment: I suspect that either I've misunderstood something or you checked the wrong thing. There is no way to install two applications with same application package name.

Comment: In my samsung galaxy Y device, I have the applications maps, Navigation, places. All 3 have the same package name com.google.android.apps and same label Called Maps. I have used this code to get the installed application.

Comment: What you received is a list of activities that can be launched from application launcher. It's not a list of applications installed on device. Some applications can have multiple entry point activities and some applications might not have such entry points at all. To get list of installed packages take a look at `PackageManager.getInstalledPackages()` - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add one little clarification that wasn't mentioned here.

Although there can't be two apps with the same package name, there can be several launcher activities within one app that user can see in launcher app. Yes, as you noticed, standard "Maps" application ("com.google.android.apps.maps" package) has several launcher activities like "Local", "Navigation", "Maps". It doesn't matter for user if these "apps" (or activities, in developer terms) are implemented in one application package or not.

Activity name ("com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity", you can retrieve this string by `rInfo.activityInfo.name`) is not unique itself too, because anyone can create an app with unique package name and an activity located in java package com.google.android.maps called MapsActivity.

Thus, if you want to find unique identifier for all these launcher activities, you should use combination of both app package name ("com.google.android.apps.maps") and activity name ("com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity").