# Is there a unique id for applications like IOS vendor id?

Tags: android

Is there a unique id for every Android application that changes when the application is re-installed? Some people say `Application Id = Package Name` for Android applications but I need a unique identifier to track applications.

EDIT: I need something other than **package name** because Although package name is unique for applications it's not unique for devices/users. For example, my app has a package name like `com.example.myapp`, it's same as every device that has the app. And yet it doesn't change when I re-install the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique ID of Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951917/unique-id-of-android-app)

Comment: **`Yes, the package name`**

Comment: @Nilu As I already said in the question, I'm not looking for that kind of id

Comment: than you need to set unique from backend side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement for one of my apps. What I did, is whenever the app is running for a first time after install, it connects to my server and requests a new unique ID. It's similar to authentication process, yet it runs automatically on first app launch.

Also, there is one more thing you might find useful. There is such thing as **Linux user ID**, it's unique for each app installation.

> At install time, Android gives each package a distinct Linux user ID.
>   The identity remains constant for the duration of the package's life
>   on that device. On a different device, the same package may have a
>   different UID; what matters is that each package has a distinct UID on
>   a given device.

Comment: Thanks, how do I get Linux UID programatically? Should I use Package Manager?

Comment: @Egek92 - Use `PackageManager` and `getApplicationInfo()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to change upon reinstallation of app, it is better to create a UUID in your app and save it in `SharedPreferences`. Then you will need to check `SharedPreferences` each time you need this identifier. If it exists, use it and if not regenerate it and save it.
The only draw back of this approach is that if user do a `clear data` on the app, this id will be lost. If it is important for you to not lost it in this case, you can save it in a file so as it only deletes when your app is deleted.

Other than this, you can use `androidId` which is mostly stays the same even upon reinstallation of app and is a better approach to track each installation uniquely, although its has some details to note [specially on android `oreo`](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is the purpose of this identification. For privacy, you shouldn't not be able to identify certain user with your application.

You can follow this article [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html)

And depending on your requirement of the scope, resettability, uniqueness and integrity of that ID, you can choose the one that works for you best.